# How to set height of angular ui-grid so that it will fit its parent container

Tags: html, angularjs, grid, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to use [Angular UI-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) . It works well, but it always small with a scroll bar on the y-axis (You can just visit there home page to view the two examples there, the height of the grids there are the basic grid).

In the docs I have seen that "height" can be given, but I do not want the scroll bar at all.
I want the grid to fit the entire container (page) and to scroll the grid using the browsers scroll-bars.

I have looked everywhere (and in the css) and could not find a solution,
can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The ui-grid will just take all the space in the div element it is added in. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/hcG0ucnCCbIFbVDqewkr?p=preview take a look at the example and try playing with the .grid in the css.

```
 <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
```